# How to make my own “live listen” app on iOS

Tags: ios

I tried to use "live listen" by my beats headset but failed. It seems that "live listen" feature is enabled only for AirPods (Pro) or "made for iPhone" hearing aids.
And I also tried to switch an input device to builtInMic by setPreferredInput on Swift Playgrounds.
It succeeded but it also switches the output to built in speaker.
Since I want to keep the output to the headset, I failed to make my own "live listen".

Is "live listen" setting an private API?
Or is it possible to make my own "live listen" app if I have AirPods?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey! Sorry I'm not familiar with live listen for AirPods, etc — but what about SiriKit? I'm fairly certain there's a way to create a "live listen" intent. Let me know if this is an option for you!

Comment: I could not find any information about “live listen” intent in SiriKit by Googling. Could you provide it?